# Firebase database rules: users permission

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to make different permission for different user roles.

For example, when the user is not **super-owner**, don't let him write in my items table.

This is what I tried to do:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "items": {
        ".write": "auth.authority == 'super-owner'"
    }
  }
  }
```

But I notice that the `authority` field is stored in my `users` node I created on my own and is releated to the Firebase `auth`. How I can access `users->authority` of current logged in user through the rules?

Update: I did try this:

```
".read": "root.child('users/'+auth.uid).authority.exists()",
```

but I get **Error saving rules - Line 10: No such method/property 'authority'.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because `root.child('users/'+auth.uid)` returns instance of `DataSnapshot` which does not have `authority` property of course. But it has `hasChild` method.

For full list of methods about `DataSnapshot` visit the following link.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot.

Try this.

```
".read": "root.child('users/'+auth.uid).hasChild('authority')",
".write": "root.child('users/'+auth.uid).hasChild('authority') && root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/authority').val() == 'super-owner'"
```

or this

```
".read": "root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/authority').exists()",
".write": "root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/authority').exists() && root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/authority').val() == 'super-owner'"
```

or the **shortest version**

```
".read": "root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/authority').val() !== null",
".write": "root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/authority').val() == 'super-owner'"
```

Comment: And what about the value? How I can chek if it's super owner?

Comment: root.child('users/'+auth.uid).hasChild('authority') && root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/authority').val() == 'super-owner'

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!